# Invalid access to memory location on 64-bit Strawberry Perl only

Tags: windows, perl, strawberry-perl, libyaml

Hi I am trying to get a Perl program running on Windows 64-bit using Strawberry Perl version 5.20, the 64-bit version. I have no problems running the 32-bit version (32-bit Strawberry Perl on 32-bit Windows), but it lacks the memory capabilities of the 64-bit.

All of the required modules compile correctly, however when I run the program I get the following error:

> Can't load 'C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/YAML/XS/LibYAML/LibYAML.xs.dll' for module YAML::XS::LibYAML:
>   load_file:Invalid access to memory location at 
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/XSLoader.pm line 68.
>   at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/YAML/XS/LibYAML.pm line 7.

Any ideas on what is going on? Or how I can try to fix this? I have tried reinstalling both Perl and the modules.

Comment: What processor do you have in your system? Can you run: `wmic cpu get Name,AddressWidth,Version` and post the results?

Comment: AddressWidth  Name
64            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31270 @ 3.40GHz