# Perl on Windows: 32bit or 64bit?

Tags: windows, perl, 32bit-64bit, strawberry-perl

For several scripting tasks, our team currently uses [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) 5.14 / 32bit and I'm looking into upgrading to the latest 5.24(+) version.

I have always used the 32-bit version on Windows, and I found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697954/does-64-bit-perl-includes-all-32-bit-perl-modules) [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336342/invalid-access-to-memory-location-on-64-bit-strawberry-perl-only) that the 32-bit version may be [a little bit less troublesome](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/1jm2vd/32_bit_vs_64_bit_activestate_for_windows/) in general, but how true that is today, I have no clue.

In general, today on my Win7-Win10 installations, I try to install the 64bit version of a tool if there is one available, but since perl is not a tool but a toolbox, the choice seems a bit more complicated.

Of course, it's no problem at all having two Strawberry Portable/ZIP Versions in parallel on the same box, but obviously we as a team want to minimize version variations as much as possible, so I guess the question could be summed up as a

**TL;DR**: Default to 32-bit Strawberry Perl and use the 64-bit one when needed, *or* default to 64-bit Strawberry Perl and use the 32-bit one when a package only has a 32-bit version?

I checked, and if it's relevant, the only packages we currently have in addition to the Strawberry 5.14 defaults are `DBD::Oracle`, `HTML::Formatter`, `XML::LibXML` and `XML::LibXSLT`

Oh, and **of course**, *"it doesn't matter, because there are only some obscure modules, or you'll know exactly when it matters (e.g. 32bit vs 64-bit MS Office)"* is indeed a valid answer, which doesn't make the question per se opinion based IMHO.

---

I'll note that the Strawberry homepage lists both the 64-bit as well as the 32-bit version as recommended, but lists the 64-bit version first.

Comment: Well, it's an opinion, but mine is - there's no problem running 64bit.

Comment: @Sobrique - which cpan modules do you use with which SB Perl 64bit version? That might make some good info to showcase that 64bit is in fact no problem?

Comment: A vast medly, because I end up downloading almost anything someone mentions on Stack Overflow. (In Strawberry perl).

Comment: If you know which modules you're using on the old perl, why not just start there? Just install a new instance of the 64-bit, install the modules, and test out your scripts. I've never had any issues after switching to 64-bit a long time ago, and in my development, perform auto-testing of my distributions across both 32 and 64 bit perls. My automation distributions takes care of installing all dependency modules automatically. Never had an issue with a clash

Comment: another option, is use 'autobundle'. Here's a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057829/openssl-upgrade-in-strawberry-perl/40059315#40059315) I show how to do this. You can ignore the berrybrew parts (that's not the focus of this comment). autobundle allows you to make a list of all currently installed modules in one perl, and easily re-install them all in another

Comment: @nwellnhof - Nick, "picking" on you as the first closer: I wonder whether you think that the 32bit and 64bit versions are technically equivalent, and therefore you think it is a purely opinion based question, or whether you close-voted because you think that the question as-asked is potentially opinon-based, regardless of any Perl technicalities?

Comment: @ChankeyPath - because, you know, stating that there are very little / or only obscure modules that only work e.g. on 32-bit and therefore *it doesn't matter* would be a far more useful comment/answer that close-voting. Just sayin'. Cheers.

Comment: It's simply impossible to give a definite answer to the question. Whether one prefers 32- or 64-bit Strawberry Perl depends on too many factors. Maybe I should have chosen "too broad" as reason to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb I've always used during architecture changes is to examine your tool-chain.  If nothing is holding you back, move to the newer architecture.  If some part of your tool chain is 32-bit only, then deal with 32-bit for a little longer.

For example, I have a customer who requires NotesSQL, and for some time they only provided a 32-bit version of their library.  This meant sticking with a 32-bit ODBC connection and a 32-bit perl.  Now all the tools I depend on are available in 64-bit.  Odds are, at this late date, that the same is true for you.